# Getting next closest date from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im trying to get the closest date to today from array "dates".

Example: Today is 2011-09-10 -> next closest date from JSON file is "2012-12-20" -> $('div').append('date1: ' + dates.date1);

Example 2: Today is 2012-12-21 -> next closest date from JSON file is "2012-12-25" -> $('div').append('date2: ' + dates.date2);

Tried a few solutons, but without success. Need help! Here is JSON file.

```
[
    {
        "fields": {
            "field1": "Field1",
            "field2": "Field2"
        },
        "dates": {
            "date1": "2012-12-20",
            "date2": "2012-12-25",
            "date3": "2012-12-31"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever it was that had a solution like this.... **put it back please** :)

```
var json = [
    {
    "fields": {
        "field1": "Field1",
        "field2": "Field2"
    },
    "dates": {
        "date1": "2012-12-20",
        "date2": "2012-12-25",
        "date3": "2009-12-31",
        "date4": "2010-12-31"
    }}
]
var dates = [];
var jsondates = json[0].dates;
for (var i in jsondates) {
    dates.push(new Date(jsondates[i]))
}
dates.sort(function(a,b){
  return Math.abs(1 - a / new Date()) - Math.abs(1 - b / new Date())
});

// dates is now ordered by closest to today with index 0 being the closest.
```

all it needed was a sort algorithm

### Edit

Just read the question more closely... you don't want any dates previous too current date to be considered even if it is closer... this is not to hard either:

```
for (var i in jsondates) {
    if(new Date(jsondates[i]) >= new Date())
        dates.push(new Date(jsondates[i]))
}
dates.sort(function(a,b){
  return Math.abs(1 - a / new Date()) - Math.abs(1 - b / new Date())
});
```

Comment: This does still not work: The Date object doesn't recognise the "2011-12-12" format. See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to understand why. Also, define the current date, instead of calling `new Date()` three times a loop.

Comment: @Rob W also that documentation addresses ECMAScript 1st Edition and js 1.0.  ECMA is at 5 now and js is at 1.8.5

Answer (score 1):

Assume `array` to be the variable which holds that parsed JSON string. This is a way to achieve your goal:

```
var dates = array[0].dates;
var current = (new Date).getTime();
var closest = null;
var closestDateDif = current;
var i, j;
for (i in dates){
  j = current - new Date(dates[i]).getTime();
  //j is a temporary variable which now holds the difference between the time stamp and now

  if(j >= 0 && j < closestDateDif){
    closest = i;
    closestDateDif = j;
  }
}
//dates[closest] holds the closest date.
//You can even calculate the remainder between now and the next time stamp, for example:
var daysLeft = Math.floor(closestDateDif/24e3/3600);
```

### Improved algoritm

This version uses the Date object only once.

```
var dates = array[0].dates;
var now = new Date();
var UNIQUENAME =  "current/randomstringwhich doesn't exist in date";
//this variable is used to determine whether you've reached the current date or not

function pad(x){return x>9?x:"0"+x}
now.getFullYear() + "-" + pad(now.getMonth()+1) + "-" + pad(now.getDate());
var tmp = [[UNIQUENAME, now]];
for(i in dates){
  tmp.push([i, dates[i]]);
}
tmp.sort(function(x,y){return x[1].localeCompare(y[1])});
for(var i=0; i<tmp.length; i++){
   if(tmp[i][0] == UNIQUENAME){
     i++;
     break;
   }
}
if(tmp[i]) alert("The closest date is at " + tmp[i][1] + ". Description: " + tmp[i][0]);
else alert("All dates are in the past!")
//tmp[i][1] holds the value of the closest next date
//tmp[i][0] holds the value of the descriptor.
```

Comment: Thx for answer! But error log says:

x[1] is undefined
-> tmp.sort(function(x,y){return x[1].localeCompare(y[1])});

Comment: Edited answer. I changed `var tmp = [now];` to the expected `var tmp = [[UNIQUENAME, now]];`. It should now work as intended!

Answer (score 0):

I realize there's already an accepted answer, but there's a much simpler way to do this, as long as you have ECMA5 Arrays & Objects available (you can shim them on older browsers, and you should).

First, grab the dates from the JSON String:

```
var dates = [], datesObj = JSON.parse(string)[0].dates;
for(var d in datesObj){ dates.push(d); }
```

You can save yourself some trouble here by storing the dates as an array, as you're already throwing away the keys.

Once you have them as an array, you can get them sorted, without previous dates with a one liner: (broken into multiple lines for readability)

```
var upcomingDates = dates.map(function(d){
    return new Date(d.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/,"$2/$3/$1"));
  }).filter(function(d){
    return d < new Date();
  }).sort(function(a,b){
    return a - b;
  });
```

Using the native array methods will save you a lot of headache. If you then need them to display like you had them before, you can use `Date.getFullYear`, `Date.getDate()`, and `Date.getMonth()` to format them.